# Joomla Fatal error: Allowed memory size after joomla update

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, fatal-error

hi i am facing some error in my joomla site after update joomla version to 3.4

Server Info :

Php 5.4.41

MySQL 5.6.17

### Apache 2.2.27

### Site Name : http://www.yousfis.com/

i enable display error by add these link in configuration.php

ini_set( 'display_errors', true );
error_reporting( E_ALL );

and facing these error in frontend

Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, '', to be a valid callback in /home/yousfisc/domains/yousfis.com/public_html/libraries/joomla/filter/input.php on line 988

### Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2474379033 bytes) in /home/yousfisc/domains/yousfis.com/public_html/libraries/joomla/filter/input.php on line 995

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: You get it on all pages or just some? It might be caused by extension not Joomla core. Try to open other pages of your site.

Answer (score 0):

Dissable eaccelerator from 'Select PHP Version' of your cpanel. Problem solve.

Answer (score 0):

Your web page is not very big and you don´t have any complicated funcionality on page.

So probably you have this memory issue because you are doing "live" resizing of very large photos.

Try 2 things:

1. htaacess - add line

   php_value memory_limit 32M

   ** (or 64M or 128M)
2. Review your images and try to reduce image size wtih some external program (ex. Photoshop)